# Nginx cache seems to make chrome fail

Tags: linux, proxy, chrome, nginx, cache

I'm running a MeteorJs app on a OVH vps, behind a Nginx proxy with a Let's encrypt SSL Cert.

Previously, I was using heroku to host my app.

I'm now facing a problem : on chrome, I "often" get that error message in the console logs : `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`

I've browsed the web and seen that it's related to the cache, many SO questions says that I have to remove the cache.

The problem is that doing so (with ctrl + f5 or from the chrome tools panel) sometime works but it seems very random, and simple refreshes will eventually bring back the error.

I've modified my Nginx .conf to add several lines I've seen while browsing for a solution :

```
server_tokens off; # for security-by-obscurity: stop displaying nginx version

# this section is needed to proxy web-socket connections
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    ''      close;
}

# HTTP
server {
    listen 80 default_server; # if this is not a default server, remove "default_server"
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html; # root is irrelevant
    index index.html index.htm; # this is also irrelevant

    server_name www.talkalang.com talkalang.com; # the domain on which we want to host the application. Since we set "default_server" previously, nginx will answer all hosts anyway.

    # redirect non-SSL to SSL
    location / {
        rewrite     ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
    }
}

# HTTPS server
server {
    listen 443 ssl; # we enable SPDY here
    server_name www.talkalang.com talkalang.com; # this domain must match Common Name (CN) in the SSL certificate

    root html; # irrelevant
    index index.html; # irrelevant

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/talkalang.com/fullchain.pem; # full path to SSL certificate and CA certificate concatenated together
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/talkalang.com/privkey.pem; # full path to SSL key

    # performance enhancement for SSL
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;

    # safety enhancement to SSL: make sure we actually use a safe cipher
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-$

    # config to enable HSTS(HTTP Strict Transport Security) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security
    # to avoid ssl stripping https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSL_stripping#SSL_stripping
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000;";
        # If your application is not compatible with IE <= 10, this will redirect visitors to a page advising a browser update
    # This works because IE 11 does not present itself as MSIE anymore
    if ($http_user_agent ~ "MSIE" ) {
        return 303 https://browser-update.org/update.html;
    }

    # pass all requests to Meteor
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade; # allow websockets
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr; # preserve client IP
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

        # this setting allows the browser to cache the application in a way compatible with Meteor
        # on every applicaiton update the name of CSS and JS file is different, so they can be cache infinitely (here: 30 days)
        # the root path (/) MUST NOT be cached
        if ($uri != '/') {
            #expires 30d;
        }
        add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
        proxy_cache off;
        expires off;
    }
}
```

Here are the lines I added :

```
add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
proxy_cache off;
expires off;
```

And it still doesn't solve the problem. I'm all out of ideas, I'm really not familiar with admin sys and ubuntu, specially nginx.

The problem is that the app is used by hundred of non-technical people every day, and I can't just ask them to spam ctrl+f5 until it works.

Has anyone an idea ? Any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks you.